# get the specified outpot using php 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, 2d, sorting

I have got a 2d array called $myarray, and when I using var_dump($myarray), it gives me the following:

```
  array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "EUR" [1]=> string(9) "43,543.23" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "USD" [1]=> string(9) "13,432.34" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "GBP" [1]=> string(8) "3,432.21" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "CAD" [1]=> string(8) "2,321.34" } }
```

But I want the output to be the follwing format:

```
Totals
GBP 3,432.21
USD 13,432.34
EUR 43,543.23
CAD 2,321.34
```

I assume that I need to sort the array to be:

```
GBP 3,432.21
USD 13,432.34
EUR 43,543.23
CAD 2,321.34
```

and add "Totals", "" into the array, I might be wrong, soanybody could help me with that, any help will be greatly appreciated! I want it to be done in a programmatic way! how to sort the array $myarray to the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not add anything non-data related to your array. You the string "Totals" should not be included in your array. If you just want the output, I suggest a better way to solve your problem :

```
<?php 
   class MyMoney {
      var $type;
      var $value;

      public function __toString() {
         return $type."  ".$value."\n";    
      }
   }

   $output="Totals:\n";
   // $data is an array of MyMoney objects
   foreach( $entry in $data ) {
      $output.= (string) $entry;
   }

   dump($output);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely the way to go: keep data and functionality together!  (And apparently the order wasn't mandatory)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost right.

Don't add the 'Totals' into the array.  It is not data, mere decoration.  For the rest, I wouldn't 'dump' the array, but e.g. for a string from it.  As a rule, don't change your data  especially for output formatting reasons, you'll find yourself removing the 'Totals' entry in the next function processing the data...:

Also, you want to control the iteration order; therefore you can iterate over the desired keys instead of over the array itself:

```
$output="Totals:\n";
foreach( $currency in array("GBP","USD","EUR","CAD") ) {
   $entry=$data[$currency];
   $output.=$currency." ".$entry[1]."\n";
}

dump($output);
```

EDIT - added the bit about ordering

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're describing but perhaps it can be of use in your situation:

```
$myArray = array(
        "title" => "Totals",
        "data" => array(
                "GBP" => "3,432.21",
                "USD" => "13,432.34",
                "EUR" => "43,543.23",
                "CAD" => "2,321.34"
        )
);

var_dump($myArray);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "Totals"
  ["data"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["GBP"]=>
    string(8) "3,432.21"
    ["USD"]=>
    string(9) "13,432.34"
    ["EUR"]=>
    string(9) "43,543.23"
    ["CAD"]=>
    string(8) "2,321.34"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$output = "Totals<br>";
foreach ($myarray as $value)
{
    $output .= $value[0].' '.$value[1].'<br>';
}
echo $output;
?>
```